# python simple json problem with a unicode string url "link": "http:\/\/www.mydomain.com"?

Tags: python, simplejson

i have a dictionary when i pass it over `simplejson.dumps(dict)` the json output has put some sort of encoding on a string url?

```
"link": "http:\/\/www.mydomain.com"
```

How can i stop this?

Im using app engine simplejson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem with this. This encoding for the forward slash is [perfectly valid](http://json.org/). If the other side can't decode this then it's their JSON library that is broken.

Comment: Hmmm - Ok so what you are saying is this encoding is perfectly acceptable - so can i ask why the twitter api doesn't use these backslashes in their json output>

Comment: The JSON specification says you can escape a forward slash, but it doesn't actually say you must escape it. So either is correct (but a JSON decoder must accept both). See http://www.json.org/ A string can contain any unicode character unescaped except " \ or a control character (so that includes /), and \ may be followed by a variety of things including /